# Modified Richardson Iteration - How to implement

Tags: matlab, math

I have an assignment to do in matlab. I have to implement the modified richardson iteration. I couldn't really understand the algorithm but i came up with this:

```
A = [9 1 1;
    2 10 3;
    3 4 11];  
b = [10;
    19;
    0];  
x = [0;
    0;
    0];  
G=eye(3)-A; %I-A  
z = [0,x'];  
for k=1:30  
  x = G*x + b;  
  z = [k,x'];  
  fprintf('Number of Iterations: %d \n', k);  
display(z);  
end
```

The output i recieve is wrong and i don't really know why. Any help is well recieved. Thanks!

Comment: Could you refer us to an introduction of the modified richardson iteration, and could you provide an example of desired output?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_Richardson_iteration

It is supposed to solve an _Ax=b_  system. The more iterations the more precise the result. The output should be an improving series of solutions for the system.

Comment: According to the Wikipedia page you provided, your algorithm isn't really the Modified Richardson Iteration. There are several incorrect calculations e.g. `G=eye(3)-A; %I-A` and `  x = G*x + b;`.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `omega` parameter. From the wiki page, the iteration is:

```
x(k+1) = x(k) + omega*( b - A*x(k) )
       = (I - omega*A)*x(k) + omega*b
```

where `omega` is a scalar parameter that has to be chosen appropriately.

So you need to change your calculation of `G` to:

```
G = eye(3)-omega*A;
```

and the calculation of `x` inside the loop to:

```
x = G*x + omega*b;
```

The wiki page discusses how the value of `omega` can be chosen. For your particular case, `omega = 0.1` seems to work well.